# How to combine Column1,Column2(Column3) and in the column 3 I had some NULLS. Instead of Nulls I need Column1,Column2

Tags: sql

How to comabine Column1,Column2(Column3) and in the column 3 I had some NULLS. Instead of Nulls I need Column1,Column2

Comment: The question is unclear. Also, need to know what the database is (Oracle? Postgres? MySQL? etc.) the syntax used differs by database.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select concat(column1, Column2, Column3) Concatenatedvalue from table1.
```

I assumed this is SQL server, concat will take care of null values . Please make sure not to use null values because CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL will be ON as default settings for most of the databases as long as it is not changed. 
My database has CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON feature.

```
 SELECT 'abc' + NULL fromplus , concat('ABC', Null) fromconcat ;  

 Output: 

 fromplus   fromconcat
 NULL        ABC
```

If you see I got null from '+' and valid value from concat.